# What is the difference between Runtime.getRuntime().exec() and double click to execute batch file?

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, cmd, runtime

What is the difference between Runtime.getRuntime().exec() and double click to execute batch file?

when I execute batch file by using Runtime.getRuntime().exec()(case 1) like this,

```
String[] command = {"cmd.exe", "/C", "Start", "D:\\test.bat"};
Process p =  Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

or

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start "+"D:\\test.bat")
```

a new cmd console window open, and launching test.bat.

and if I try to execute test.bat by mouse double click on my desktop(case 2), 
it also open in a new cmd console window, and launching application.

but problem is occurred when I try to stop test.bat. I using 'Ctrl-C' to stop batch file,

when I using 'Ctrl-C' in case 1, cmd console stop but still remain window and prompt line.

but when I using 'Ctrl-C' in case 2, cmd console stop and close the window!!

I want make close the window in case 1. but I don't know how.. how can I do that??

ps. I try to write 'exit' in test.bat, but it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a problem with `Runtime.exec()` in java, you have the same problem if you open a cmd console and type your command. It's because `start` doesn't exit (whereas `cmd` with flag C exits when command is finished).

It doesn't work by adding `exit` at the end of test.bat because you killed by ctrl+c the execution of the script, and exit statement is not executed.

You could try to change your call as follow to fix the problem:

```
cmd /C start cmd /C test.bat
```